# How expand size virtual disk in virtual server 2005?

Tags: virtual, disk

I'm using Virtual Server 2005 and working with a virtual hard disk 16GB.
I need expand this virtual disk to 20GB. 
Thanks.
Beatriz

Answer (score 2):

You could try [VMToolkit](http://vmtoolkit.com/). It's free!